# The degree of a vertex in the grapf of a erdos graph

Tags: random

I have the following question: Consider a random graph on nvertices, where between any two vertices there is an edge with probability p = c/n, (alternatively, no edge with probability 1-p) all edges are independent. Using the characteristic functions find limit in distribution of the degree of a vertex (i.e., the number of incident edge at this vertex) in the graph.

I think I am on the right track when I am assuming that the random variable X which denotes the degree of a random vertex is distributed according Bin(n, c/n) hence this would mean we can solce this question by utilizing the generating function of the binomial distrubtion.

Are my assumptions correct? And if yes, can you provide a complete solution to the question? I would be very thankful! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am also thinking like this:

Let p(x) denote the number of vertices in the graph which is n. Then there are n-1 edges(2 dots that get connected wich gives 1 edge), hence y is then  Bernoulli(c/n) and if you sum (n-1) random variables with this distribution you get Bin(n-1, c/n).

But once again, not sure if this is correct.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).